# Hide Content on each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each, jquery-events

How could I hide content from each DIV on `mouseenter`?

```js
var quick = document.querySelectorAll(".quickview");
var quickwrap = document.querySelectorAll(".view");


quickwrap.forEach(div => div.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
    $.each(quick, function(){
      $(this).hide()
    })
  })
);
```

```css
div{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(50, 190, 100, 0.7);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 50px;
  color: white; 
}
.view{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  left:20px;
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be doing this already.

Comment: Did you mean hide all other element's besides the one being entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each inside an Each is not needed.

`$('.view')` will select all elements with class view, and use `.on` will add the event you defined to each of those elements.

To hide the current `mouseenter` element's content just use `$(this).find('.quickview').hide();`

```js
$('.view').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $(this).find('.quickview').hide();
});
```

```css
div{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(50, 190, 100, 0.7);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 50px;
  color: white; 
}
.view{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  left:20px;
  margin:1em;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="view">
  <div class="quickview">  
    <span class="viewtxt">  Quick View</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.view').hover(
      function() {
        // on hover
        $(this).find('.quickview').hide();
      }, function() {
        // on remove hover
        $(this).find('.quickview').show();
      }
    );  
});
```

This will hide `.quickview div` on hover from specific `.view div` and on remove hover show it again.